# Assets are not loading with https. How to force https not http?

Tags: wordpress

My css/js assets which are loaded from items like:

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

And for plug-ins like Scroll Triggered Box - http://www.dreamgrow.com/dreamgrow-scroll-triggered-box/

These assets are all loading over http which is causing the site to break as the blog is hosted over https.

How can you have WordPress use https?

Comment: what is the result of `if ( is_ssl() )`?

Answer (score -3):

You can try a plugin like [WordPress HTTPS (SSL)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/) and see if that solves the issue. I have had to manually go through some code to change the paths to use https but most of the time these issues can be solved with a simple plugin.